# Linkedin direct share without oauth2

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

How to share text and url in Linkedin from an iOS app. Is it possible without oAuth2 authentication  and if not can anyone help me with oAuth2 integration and sharing simply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually very simple.  Just fill in your URL using the format below...

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}
```

Source: **[Official LinkedIn Share URL Documentation.](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin)**

But then, you probably also want to share other information, right?  Like `title`, `description`, and all that other good stuff.  Do that using `og:` meta tags in your HTML header, like so...

- `<meta property='og:title' content='Title of the article"/>`
- `<meta property='og:image' content='//media.example.com/ 1234567.jpg"/>`
- `<meta property='og:description' content='Description that will show in the preview"/>`
- `<meta property='og:url' content='//www.example.com/URL of the article" />`

Source: **[Official Microsoft "Making Your Website Shareable on LinkedIn" Documentation](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en)**.

Want to make sure you did it correctly?  That's the easiest part.  Copy the URL of the website you want to share, like `example.com`, and input it here...

**[Official LinkedIn Post Inspector](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/)**

Answer (score 1):

No,

Its not possible to Exploit Share Api without Authentication.
LinkedIN has its Rest API, that you can use

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin

To tried it out check out APIs, you can play at [APIGEE](https://apigee.com/console/linkedin)

Git Libraries for Auth 2.0

https://github.com/jeyben/IOSLinkedInAPI

https://github.com/mrugraj/MVLinkedIn-iOS (Under development)